# How not to run a batch file and python in parallel?

Tags: python, batch-file, sequence

I have below scripts

1)

```
  os.chdir("C:\\RTM3Run_Full\\Python Codes")
  os.startfile("2015_RUNcvm_64_Crash.bat")
```

2)

```
 for i in range(settings.loop):
    ....
```

I want to start the "for i in range(settings.loop):" section (i.e. part 2)after the batch file is completely finished. But it only runs part 1) and part 2) in parallel. I know I should be able to set up a pause function to wait. But I don't know how long part 1) takes. Anyone know there is other smarter way to run 1) and 2) in sequence?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`os.startfile` simulates a click in the explorer. It means that your batch file will run in background.

Replace this:

```
os.chdir("C:\\RTM3Run_Full\\Python Codes")
os.startfile("2015_RUNcvm_64_Crash.bat")
```

by a proper blocking subprocess call, and since it's a batch file and you want to avoid `shell=True`, prefix by `cmd /c`, as an argument list. Also don't `chdir`, just use current working directory argument so the current directory isn't changed:

```
rc = subprocess.call(["cmd","/c","2015_RUNcvm_64_Crash.bat"],cwd=r"C:\RTM3Run_Full\Python Codes")
```

you may want to check the return code, or use `check_call` to stop with an exception if the batch file returns a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on this [link](https://datasciencebeginners.com/2018/10/24/running-python-processes-in-parallel-getting-started/)

Suppose that you have this commands in separates scripts, you can do this:

```
import multiprocessing
import os                                              

# Creating the tuple of all the processes which can be run in parallel
all_parallel_processes = ('script_A.py', 'script_B.py', 'script_C.py')     

next_run = ('script_D.py')

# This block of code enables us to call the script from command line.                                                                                
def execute(process):                                                             
    os.system(f'python {process}')                                       


process_pool = Pool(processes = 4)                                                        
process_pool.map(execute, all_parallel_processes)
process_pool.map(execute, next_run)
```

Where script.d only run after a, b and c script finish (they run in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an easy solution

1)

os.chdir("C:\RTM3Run_Full\Python Codes")

os.system("2015_RUNcvm_64_Crash.bat")

2)

for i in range(settings.loop):
    ....

This assured to run part 2) after part 1) is completed.

Thanks everyone for the helps~